# Oh my zsh on windows

Tags: windows, windows-8, cygwin, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have installed Cygwin on my windows 8.1 Now I want to install ZSH and Oh My ZSH in cygwin.

I have installed ZSH in it by selecting  Shells > Zsh in Select screen.

[image]

and I found this link to install [Oh my ZSH](https://github.com/haithembelhaj/oh-my-cygwin) but when I run given command on this page

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/haithembelhaj/oh-my-cygwin/master/oh-my-cygwin.sh -O -
```

I get this output

```
Jitendra Vyas@JitendraVyas ~
$ wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/haithembelhaj/oh-my-cygwin/                                                                                                                                  master/oh-my-cygwin.sh -O -
--2013-11-06 22:49:50--  https://raw.github.com/haithembelhaj/oh-my-cygwin/maste                                                                                                                                  r/oh-my-cygwin.sh
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: E:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/e/RailsInstaller/cacert.pem
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
Resolving raw.github.com... 103.245.222.133
Connecting to raw.github.com|103.245.222.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 826 [text/plain]
Saving to: `STDOUT'

 0% [                                       ] 0           --.-K/s              #                                                                                                                                  !/bin/bash

# install apt-cyg
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/john-peterson/apt-cyg/raw/path/ap                                                                                                                                  t-cyg
chmod +x apt-cyg
mv apt-cyg /bin/apt-cyg

# install some stuff like vim and git
apt-cyg install zsh mintty vim curl git openssh git-completion git-gui gitk

#setting up vim
cp /usr/share/vim/vim73/vimrc_example.vim ~/.vimrc

# Create initial /etc/zshenv
[[ ! -e /etc/zshenv ]] && echo export PATH=/usr/bin:\$PATH > /etc/zshenv

# install OH MY ZSH
/usr/bin/env git clone git://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git ~/.oh-my-zsh
if [ -f ~/.zshrc ] || [ -h ~/.zshrc ]
then
  cp ~/.zshrc ~/.zshrc.orig;
  rm ~/.zshrc;
fi
cp ~/.oh-my-zsh/templates/zshrc.zsh-template ~/.zshrc

# setting up zsh as default
sed -i "s/$USER\:\/bin\/bash/$USER\:\/bin\/zsh/g" /etc/passwd

# et voila just start it
/usr/bin/env zsh



100%[======================================>] 826         --.-K/s   in 0.09s

2013-11-06 22:49:51 (8.64 KB/s) - written to stdout [826/826]
```

but i didn't get this screen

[image]

Comment: _Saving to: `STDOUT'_ - I don't think that's right, it should be saving to file STDOUT would be the terminal, I think?

Comment: I had this same problem, so I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/haithembelhaj/oh-my-cygwin/pull/5) to the repo owner. Now it's easier to copy and paste the installation command.

Answer (score 12):

Because of a missing line break on the source page, you missed the most important part of the install command: `sh`. The complete command should read

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/haithembelhaj/oh-my-cygwin/master/oh-my-cygwin.sh -O - | sh
```

And given that, writing to `stdout` make perfectly sense.

However, better be always careful and don't blindly pipe an unknown script to `sh`. Instead you can download the commands to a file `install.sh`

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/haithembelhaj/oh-my-cygwin/master/oh-my-cygwin.sh -O install.sh
```

Then, check what it's doing (`less install.sh`) and only then execute it

```
sh install.sh
```

Comment: O.O both of us answered "just now" (on my screen) with almost identical answers... dang

Comment: @allquixotic: Yes, nearly to the second... hehe.

Comment: @mpy thx for answer but even after running the correct command there is still problems http://screenpresso.com/=W1uae

Comment: @metalgearsolid I would suggest you execute the commands of the installation procedure (as listed in the outout in your question) manually. This way you can see which is the first problem.

Comment: @mpy I got problem only at last which is showing in screenshot

Comment: @mpy ok now i'm installing each thing one by one . First 2 had no problem but don't know how to run third install

`#setting up vim
cp /usr/share/vim/vim73/vimrc_example.vim ~/.vimrc`

Comment: @metalgearsolid Try to install `vim-common` via `apt-cyg install vim-common`. Then `cp /usr/share/vim/vim73/vimrc_example.vim ~/.vimrc` should work.

Comment: @mpy still not working http://screenpresso.com/=ZdfGg

Comment: @metalgearsolid The file you want to copy is included in `http://mirror.mcs.anl.gov/pub/cygwin/x86/release/vim/vim-common/vim-common-7.3.1152-1.tar.bz2`. Please check the contents of the `/usr/share/vim/vim73/` directory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11395/discussion-between-mpy-and-metal-gear-solid)

Answer (score 4):

If you look more closely at the github repo you just visited -- you will notice that the command line in the README.md below the repository is cut off (truncated) due to the formatting of the HTML of the page.

If you go [here](https://github.com/haithembelhaj/oh-my-cygwin/blob/master/README.md) you will see that the full command is:

`wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/haithembelhaj/oh-my-cygwin/master/oh-my-cygwin.sh -O - | sh`

...which should work.

Answer (score 3):

A little late, but you can try the following:

- In order to install **oh-my-zsh** you can run the following commands:
- with **curl**:
  `curl -L https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh | sh`
- with **wget**:
  `wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh -O - | sh`
- After installing *oh-my-zsh*, edit the file **/etc/passwd**
- If you don't have that file, then you can create it with **mkpasswd** command:
- `$ mkpasswd > /etc/passwd`
- Then you edit that file, find your user-name and replace the end of line by **/bin/zsh**
- e.g. `david:*:...:U-JHERAX\david,...:/home/david:/bin/zsh`
- Take into account that if your logon user-name has spaces, then you should rename in order to avoid problems (see section [2.16.My Windows logon name has a space in it, will this cause problems?](https://cygwin.com/faq/))
- If you want to edit the *zsh theme*, you must edit the file **/home/<user>/.zshrc** and you'll see an environment variable **`ZSH_THEM`** then you set your favorite theme, e.g. `ZSH_THEME="ys"` (more info in github site [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh))

Recomended article: [Instalar "oh my zsh" y cygwin en Windows](http://www.racotecnic.com/2013/12/instalar-zsh-con-oh-my-zsh-y-enlaces-en-menus-contextuales-en-windows-utilizando-cygwin/)
Also worth checking out: [Shortcuts to improve your bash & zsh productivity](http://www.geekmind.net/2011/01/shortcuts-to-improve-your-bash-zsh.html)

Comment: Since [oh-my-cygwin](https://github.com/haithembelhaj/oh-my-cygwin) is deprecated AND `wget`'s `--no-check-certificate` option isn't there (at least in my x86_64 Cygwin), `curl -L https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh | sh`, followed by `mkpasswd > /etc/passwd` and editing **/etc/passwd** as indicated did the trick, it seems!